MudChipField SearchText value is not updating or reflecting correctly in the UI
I'm working with a MudChipField in Blazor. I have implemented a method ClearChipAsync that should clear the SearchText and the Values in the MudChipField. However, while the SearchText value is set to an empty string in the method, it does not visually clear in the UI.

<div id="ChipSearchField">
    <MudChipField T="string" Class="mud-chip-search" Values="@Values" ValuesChanged="@((value) => ChipValuesChangedAsync(value))"
              Value="@SearchText" ValueChanged="@SearchValueChangeAsync" Placeholder="Search" Variant="Variant.Outlined"
                  ChipSize="Size.Medium" WrapChips="true" 
                  Delimiter="@Delimiter" ChipColor="Color.Default" ChipVariant="Variant.Text" Closeable="true">
</MudChipField>

@if (Values.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="clear-chip">
        <MudTooltip Text="ClearAll">
            <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.Clear" OnClick="ClearChipAsync"></MudIconButton>
        </MudTooltip>
    </div>
}
</div>

@code {
    /// <summary>
 ///List Values of the chip control.
 /// </summary>
 [Parameter]
 public List<string> Values { get; set; } = new List<string>();

 /// <summary>
 ///Input string for search filtering.
 /// </summary>
 [Parameter]
 public string SearchText { get; set; } = string.Empty;

 /// <summary>
 /// Callback for the Search ValueChanged event.
 /// </summary>
 [Parameter]
 public EventCallback<string> SearchValueChanged { get; set; }

 /// <summary>
 /// Callback for the chip list ValuesChanged event.
 /// </summary>
 [Parameter]
 public EventCallback<List<string>> ChipValuesChanged { get; set; }

 /// <summary>
 /// Should the text field be set to focus on render?
 /// </summary>
 [Parameter]
 public bool AutoFocus { get; set; } = false;

 /// <summary>
 /// Delimiter with a default value of space
 /// </summary>       
 public char Delimiter = ' ';

 /// <summary>
 /// Event when the clear button is clicked.
 /// </summary>
 private EventCallback<MouseEventArgs> ClearChipValues { get; set; }

 /// <summary>
 /// Event when the chip list changes.
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="values">list value from the chipset.</param>
 /// <return>Task</return>
 private async Task ChipValuesChangedAsync(List<string> values)
 {
     Values = values.Select(v => v.Trim()).Where(v => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v)).Distinct().ToList();

     await ChipValuesChanged.InvokeAsync(Values);
 }

 /// <summary>
 /// Clear chip values
 /// </summary>  
 /// <return>Task</return>
 private async Task ClearChipAsync()
 {
     SearchText = string.Empty;
     Values.Clear();
     
     await ChipValuesChanged.InvokeAsync(Values);
     await SearchValueChanged.InvokeAsync(SearchText);
     await ClearChipValues.InvokeAsync();

 }

 /// <summary>
 /// Search input value changed.
 /// </summary>  
 /// <param name="value">Search Text Value.</param>
 /// <return>Task</return>
 private async Task SearchValueChangeAsync(string value)
 {
     SearchText = value;

     await SearchValueChanged.InvokeAsync(SearchText);           
 }
}

Additional Information:

The Values collection and chips are cleared correctly.
The main issue is the search text value is not cleared.
The method SearchValueChanged.InvokeAsync(SearchText) is called to update the MudChipField.

What I've Tried:

Confirmed that SearchText is indeed set to an empty string.
Verified that StateHasChanged is called after setting the SearchText.

Does anyone have an idea why the SearchText is not clearing visually and how to resolve this issue?

Can you also share your SearchValueChangeAsync method code

@RBee
private async Task SearchValueChangeAsync(string value)
{
SearchText = value;
await SearchValueChanged.InvokeAsync(SearchText);
}

Why are you calling SearchValueChanged.InvokeAsync(SearchText) is this component a child component? Regardless, I think you should share more of your code to reproduce the error. Better if you can create a working reproducible snippet here https://trymudextensions.pages.dev/snippet

@RBee I have updated the question and shared the detailed code to reproduce the issue. Thanks

If you're passing in SearchText as a parameter and the parent component is using the SearchValueChanged EventCallback and modifying SearchText then you shouldn't assign SearchText in the SearchValueChangeAsync. Similarly in the ClearChipAsync method you shouldn't modify any of the parameters - use the EventCallbacks to notify the parent of change which will pass it down the your component as parameters.

@RBee,  I followed your suggestions, but it still isn't working. Specifically, I ensured that the parent component uses the SearchValueChanged EventCallback to modify SearchText. However, I did not assign SearchText in the SearchValueChangeAsync method, nor did I modify any parameters in the ClearChipAsync method. Instead, I used the EventCallbacks to notify the parent of changes, which then passed them down to my component as parameters.

Unfortunately with the code so far I cannot reproduce the error. If you'd like more help then please use the snippet link in my earlier comment to create a reproducible environment with the error you encounter.

Hi @RBee, I'm able to reproduce the issue with the same code which I shared in the snippet as you suggested. But, unfortunately I'm unable to generate the snippet link to share. Currently, "Try MudExtensions (trymudextensions.pages.dev)" does not have a built-in feature to save snippets directly or generate shareable links for snippets. It's primarily a playground to test and experiment with MudBlazor components.

You could try use "@ref" to clear the bind directly:
<MudChipField @ref="field1" ...

@code{
    private MudChipField<string> field1;

    private async Task ClearChipAsync()
    {
        field1.Values.Clear();
...

